# Javascript/jQuery - Adding custom html attribute to parent div based on the value inside a child <a href> tag matching the current webpage link

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom-manipulation

I am trying to add a custom HTML attribute to a parent `<div>` tag after matching the relative path of the current webpage with the `<a href>` tag nested inside some other divs within that parent.

Here's my example:

```html
<!--Section 1 Nav-->
<div class="wizard-step" data-wizard-type="step">
  <div class="wizard-wrapper">
    <div class="wizard-label">
      <div class="wizard-title">
        <a href="/relative/path/to/web/page/section1/"> Section 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Section 2 Nav-->
<div class="wizard-step" data-wizard-type="step">
  <div class="wizard-wrapper">
    <div class="wizard-label">
      <div class="wizard-title">
        <a href="/relative/path/to/web/page/section2/"> Section 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Section 3 Nav-->
<div class="wizard-step" data-wizard-type="step">
  <div class="wizard-wrapper">
    <div class="wizard-label">
      <div class="wizard-title">
        <a href="/relative/path/to/web/page/section3/"> Section 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
.... (many other sections)
```

I have to add the custom attribute `data-wizard-state="current"` to one of the parent div `<div class="wizard-step" data-wizard-type="step">` if the relative path of the current webpage matches the `<a href>` within that div for each *section*.
I'm familiar with the concept of `parentNode` and `children` but it seems I'm not quite there yet or maybe I'm using the wrong concept entirely. How can I achieve this?

Any help is appreciated. Have a great day. Thank you!

Comment: The link is so secured by tags ! 4 divs are wrapped around 1 link.

Comment: Yeah, this is solely for UI customization and the css classes are defined that way (I'm using a custom theme library). I tried using the conventional `<ul>` and `<li>` way instead but the UI looked much different and would not suit my purpose. Let me know if there's a better way of doing this. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if `window.location.pathname` matches one of the a-href-values using something similar to

```
const escapedRef = window.location.pathname.replace(/["\\]/g, '\\$&');
document // or the parent-node of your list
  .querySelectorAll(`a[href^="${escapedRef}"]`) // adding a startwith to match query and hash too
  .forEach((node) => {
     console.log(node);
     node // a
       .parentNode // .wizard-title
       .parentNode // .wizard-label
       .parentNode // .wizard-wrapper
       .parentNode // .wizard-step
       .setAttribute("data-wizard-state","current");
  });
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you for this solution.